# Post Processing Stack with URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

I am using PPS with URP in Unity2019.3.7. My Question is how can i ignore UI Layer. Canvas Render mode is WorldSpace and i am using same camera on which i put the PostProcessing Component. i attached images by the way.

[image: ,]

[image]

Comment: No, I don't think you can.

Comment: have a UI camera?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but can't you simply deactivate `UI` in the cameras culling mask?

Comment: @bugfinder no buddy just one main camera

Comment: @aalmigthy I tried but didn’t work

Comment: No @NaveedAbbas I meant HAVE a UI camera

Comment: Ohhh ok. Yahhh that canvas is set to world space so...yahhh camera is there